# Cygnus Orion Context Broker Working subscription

Tags: fiware-orion, fiware-cygnus

I want to set up a working notification system between orion and cygnus.
For this I set up a subscription according to

https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/blob/master/doc/cygnus-ngsi/user_and_programmer_guide/connecting_orion.md.

It looks in my case like this:

```
(curl localhost:1026/v1/subscribeContext -s -S --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Fiware-Service: vehicles' --header 'Fiware-ServicePath: /test' -d @- | python -mjson.tool) <<EOF
{
    "entities": [
        {
            "type": "pos-test",
            "isPattern": "false",
            "id": "test"
        }
    ],
    "attributes": [
        "x_pos",
        "y_pos"
    ],
    "reference": "http://localhost:5050/notify",
    "duration": "P1M",
    "notifyConditions": [
        {
            "type": "ONCHANGE",
            "condValues": [
                "x_pos",
                "y_pos"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "throttling": "PT1S"
}
EOF
```

And than I want to insert data with the following request:

```
orcb_str = """curl correct.ip:5050/notify -v -s -S --header 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8' --header 'Accept: application/json' --header "/Fiware-Service: qsg" --header "/Fiware-ServicePath: test" -d @- <<EOF
{{
    "subscriptionId" : "5aa6731785e92e6b4cec80fc",
    "originator" : "playground",
    "contextResponses" : [
        {{
            "contextElement" : {{
                "attributes" : [
                    {{
                        "name" : "x_pos",
                        "type" : "float",
                        "value" : "{x}"
                    }},
                    {{
                        "name" : "y_pos",
                        "type" : "float",
                        "value" : "{y}"
                    }}
                ],
                "type" : "pos-test",
                "isPattern" : "false",
                "id" : "test"
            }},
            "statusCode" : {{
                "code" : "200",
                "reasonPhrase" : "OK"
            }}
        }}
    ]
}}
EOF
"""
```

The double brackets and missing values get correctly formatted in.
On the cygnus end I get this error message:

```
time=2018-03-12T13:38:58.569Z | lvl=INFO | corr=0c09ed1d-f3f9-4913-884a-b7b937ae2c6c | trans=0c09ed1d-f3f9-4913-884a-b7b937ae2c6c | srv=default | subsrv=/ | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=getEvents | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.handlers.NGSIRestHandler[286] : [NGSIRestHandler] Starting internal transaction (0c09ed1d-f3f9-4913-884a-b7b937ae2c6c)
time=2018-03-12T13:38:58.569Z | lvl=INFO | corr=0c09ed1d-f3f9-4913-884a-b7b937ae2c6c | trans=0c09ed1d-f3f9-4913-884a-b7b937ae2c6c | srv=default | subsrv=/ | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=getEvents | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.handlers.NGSIRestHandler[304] : [NGSIRestHandler] Received data ({    "subscriptionId" : "5aa674af85e92e6b4cec80fd",    "originator" : "playground",    "contextResponses" : [        {            "contextElement" : {                "attributes" : [                    {                        "name" : "x_pos",                        "type" : "float",                        "value" : "6.520416"                    },                    {                        "name" : "y_pos",                        "type" : "float",                        "value" : "0.15"                    },                    {                        "name" : "timestamp",                        "type" : "float",                        "value" : "90.884872"                    },                ],                "type" : "pos-test",                "isPattern" : "false",                "id" : "test"            },            "statusCode" : {                "code" : "200",                "reasonPhrase" : "OK"            }        }    ]})
time=2018-03-12T13:38:58.569Z | lvl=ERROR | corr=0c09ed1d-f3f9-4913-884a-b7b937ae2c6c | trans=0c09ed1d-f3f9-4913-884a-b7b937ae2c6c | srv=default | subsrv=/ | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=getEvents | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.handlers.NGSIRestHandler[315] : [NGSIRestHandler] Runtime error (null)
time=2018-03-12T13:38:58.569Z | lvl=ERROR | corr=0c09ed1d-f3f9-4913-884a-b7b937ae2c6c | trans=0c09ed1d-f3f9-4913-884a-b7b937ae2c6c | srv=default | subsrv=/ | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=warn | msg=org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog[87] : /notify
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource$FlumeHTTPServlet.doPost(HTTPSource.java:199)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:814)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:401)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:766)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:945)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:756)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector$Connection.run(SocketConnector.java:228)
        at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

And on the server sending the data I get:

```
* Connected to 192.168.0.3 (192.168.0.3) port 5050 (#0)
> POST /notify HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: 192.168.0.3:5050
> Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
> Accept: application/json
> /Fiware-Service: qsg
> /Fiware-ServicePath: test
> Content-Length: 949
> 
* upload completely sent off: 949 out of 949 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
< Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
< Content-Length: 2640
* Server Jetty(6.1.26) is not blacklisted
< Server: Jetty(6.1.26)
< 
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 500</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /notify. Reason:
<pre>    INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR</pre></p><h3>Caused by:</h3><pre>java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource$FlumeHTTPServlet.doPost(HTTPSource.java:199)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:814)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:401)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:766)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:945)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:756)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
```

Grateful for any help.

> (The timestamp attribute which appears in the log file is just left
>   here out to keep it shorter)

Comment: Ok the error was that I had a comma at the wrong position making it an invalid json object.
So the question is resolved

Comment: Happy to know you fixed the problem! I'd be great if you self-answer you own question in order to show other readers the solution to the problem. It may be useful for others. Thanks!